# Format contents titles the same as section titles

Tags: fonts, spacing, table-of-contents, formatting

How might I make section titles in `\tableofcontents` look the same as regular section titles I've formatted with the following `titlesec` commands:

```latex
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape}{\thesection. }{}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1em}{0.4em}
```

The first line principally makes section titles use small caps, the second line sets the spacing around them.

So section titles subsequently look like this:

[image: Correctly formatted titles]

I'd like the same to happen in my table of contents -- which currently looks like this:

[image: A regularly-formatted table of contents in latex labelled with the way I'd prefer it to look]

A minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

% format section title
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape}{\thesection. }{}{}

% set section titles spacing
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1em}{0.4em}

% also format subsection title
\titleformat{\subsection}{\scshape}{\thesubsection. }{}{} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{One}
\subsection{SubOne}
\subsection{SubTwo}
\section{Two}
\section{Three}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I think it would not be very good for the readability to use the same format as section heading inside the table of contents.

Comment: Please add a meaningful [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and a problem description here. Don't just link to external pages containing the LaTeX code.
External links can become invalid or inaccessible, and the question could lose any value to future visitors.

Comment: As already mentioned, please never link to external sources for MWEs. External links rot over time and thus your question will not be useful to others.

Comment: @dexteritas - wouldn't you say that the default behaviour almost exactly "format[s section titles the same] as section heading[s] inside the table of contents"? Regardless, it would be nice to find a solution to format the ToC titles with similar elegance to regular section titles, if not to make them exactly the same.

Comment: @btRooke If you mean "exactly the same", i.e., same font, same font size, same emphasis, same spacing etc. that's not the default behavior. If you mean anything else, you should clarify it in your question. Maybe you just want the same emphasis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatting of the table of contents can be customized with [`titletoc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc), a companion for `titlesec`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

% format section title
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape}{\thesection.}{.5em}{}
% set section titles spacing
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1em}{0.4em}
% set section titles in TOC
\titlecontents{section}[1.5em]{\scshape}{\contentslabel{1.5em}}{}{}

% also format subsection title
\titleformat{\subsection}{\scshape}{\thesubsection.}{.5em}{}
% format subsection titles in TOC
\dottedcontents{subsection}[3.8em]{\scshape}{2.3em}{.6pc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{One}
\subsection{SubOne}
\subsection{SubTwo}
\section{Two}
\section{Three}

\end{document}
```